# reverse URL error while using PasswordResetView in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am implementing password reset functionality using default PasswordResetView.

```
# account/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name= 'account'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'), name='login' ),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('profile/', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    path('profile/edit/', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    path('profile/password/', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='account/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='account/password_reset_done.html'), 
        name='password_reset_done'),
]
```

Even though I have defined url corresponding to **name="password_reset_done"**, I am still getting the below error when I submit email to the form rendered by accessing **password-reset/** url.
[image: Image of the error received]

[image]

I am trying to access the reset page through url. After entering email in the field and submitting, I am receiving the above mentioned error.

Comment: Can you show me how you are calling the password reset url?

Comment: I mean can you show me where you are trying to access the url in the code? Such as in the template or in a view?